# How are Ivy artifact dependencies represented in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am trying to convert an existing build from Ant + Ivy to Gradle and I cant workout how to represent this dependency in the Gradle dependencies section:

```
<dependency org="org" name="somelib" rev="1.0.0" conf="test-libs->runtime" force="true">
    <artifact name="somelib-some-artifact-name" type="jar" conf="test-libs"/>
</dependency>
```

This is how far I have gotten:

```
testRuntime(group: "org", name: "somelib", version: "1.0.0", configuration: "test-libs->runtime"){
    artifact {
        name = 'somelib-some-artifact-name'
        extension = 'jar'
        type = 'jar'
    }
}
```

Any ideas what the correct way to declare dependencies on artifacts is?